# SQl Sales Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, sum

I have a table like this
a. Member

```
memberid       name
MB001          NEERAJ RANA
```

b. Sales Header

```
transaction_id   memberid
TR01             MB001
TR02             MB001
```

c.  sales detail

```
 transaction_id  qty
 TR01                  2
 TR01                  2
 TR02                  2
```

My query:

```
select member.name,
       count(salesheader.memberid), 
       sum(salesdetail.qty) 
from member inner join salesheader on member.memberid = salesheader.memberid 
     inner join salesdetail on salesheader.transaction_id = salesdetail.transaction_id 
group by member.name
```

my output

```
staffname           totaltransaction     totalqty
NEERAJ RANA         3                    6
```

I want to output like this

```
staffname           totaltransaction     totalqty
NEERAJ RANA         2                    6
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

`COUNT(DISTINCT salesheader.memberid)` instead of `COUNT(salesheader.memberid)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could join use aggragtion function count and sum on group by name

```
select a.name, count(distinct b.transaction_id), sum(c.qty)
from Member
inner join sales_header b on a.memberid = b.memberid
inner join sales_detail c on b.transaction_id = c.transaction_id
group by a.name
```

Comment: explain the output you have ..using my query  ..anyway answer  updated with distinct